# How to modify DirectX camera

Tags: camera, directx, direct3d

Suppose I have a 3D (but not stereoscopic) DirectX game or program.  Is there a way for a second program (or a driver) to change the camera position in the game?

I'm trying to build a head-tracking plugin or driver that I can use for my DirectX games/programs.  An inertial motion sensor will give me the position of my head but my problem is using that position data to change the camera position, not with the hardware/math concerns of head tracking.

I haven't been able to find anything on how to do this so far, but iZ3D was able to create two cameras near the original camera and use it for stereoscopic stuff, so I know there exists some hook/link/connection into DirectX that makes camera manipulation by a second program possible.

If I am able to get this to work I'll release the code.

-Shane

Answer (score 1):

Hooking Direct3D calls in its nature is just hooking DLL calls. I.e. its not something special to D3D but just a generic technique. Try googling for "hook dll" or start from here: [[C++] Direct3D hooking sample](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/359794-c-direct3d-hooking-sample/). As it always happens with hooks there are many caveats and you'll have to make a pretty huge boilerplate to satisfy all needs of the hooked application.

Though, manipulation with camera in games usually gives not good results. There are at least two key features of modern PC game which will severely limit your idea:

1. Pre-clipping. Almost any game engine filters out objects that are behind the viewing plane. So when you rotate camera to a side you won't see the objects you'd expect to see in a real world - they were just not sent to D3D since game doesn't know that viewing plane has changed.
2. Multiple passes rendering. Many popular post processing effects are done in extra passes (either thru the whole scene or just part of it). Mirrors and "screens" are the most known such effects. Without knowing what camera you're manipulating with you'll most likely just break the scene.

Btw, #2 is the reason why stereoscopic mode is not 100% compatible with all games. For example, in Source engine HDR scenes are rendered in three passes and if you don't know how to distinguish them you'll do nothing but break the game. Take a look at how nVidia implements their stereoscopic mode: they make a separate hook for every popular game and even with this approach it's not always possible to get expected result.